# Wrong chessboard size in revision history

Tags: bug, pgn-viewer

When viewing the revision history of a post, the chessboard has the wrong size:

[image]

This is caused by the following CSS rule:

```
#revisions table {
    width: 100%
}
```

Tested on a Mac, with Safari and Chrome.

**EDIT:** the size is also wrong in the review queue:

[image]